# UNIX Crop multiple files from dynamic position

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a directory containing a huge amount of html files

I know that in order to find the starting point i have to use the following command

```
grep -n -m1 "/header" filename.html| cut -d':' -f1
```

and to find the end point of my crop i have to use this one

```
grep -n -m1 "footer" 39646_20160820.html | cut -d':' -f1
```

My question is: how can i crop all files in a directory using these two criteria for each file to have the start and the end of the crop of each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all lines between `/header` and `footer` for all files in the current directory:

```
sed -i.bak '\|/header|,\|footer|d' *
```

The expression `\|/header|,\|footer|` defines a range of lines that start with a line that contains `/header` and ends with a line that contains `footer`.  The command `d` tells sed to delete all lines in such a range.

`*` is a glob which refers to all files in the current directory.  If you don't want to operate on all files, change this glob.

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat File
1
/header
2
footer
3
```

To remove all lines starting with a line that contains `/header` and ending with a line containing `footer` and display the result to stdout:

```
$ sed '\|/header|,\|footer|d' File
1
3
```

To update all files in the current directory in-place:

```
$ sed -i.bak '\|/header|,\|footer|d' *
```

To verify that this worked:

```
$ cat File
1
3
```

#### Backup files

The above command creates backup files with the extension `.bak`.  If you are confident that the command does the right thing and you do not want backup files, then use:

```
sed -i '\|/header|,\|footer|d' *  # GNU/Linux
```

Or:

```
sed -i '' '\|/header|,\|footer|d' *  # OSX/BSD
```

### Keeping the range instead of deleting it

To keep the range, deleting all else:

```
sed -n '\|/header|,\|footer|p' *
```

For example, on our sample file:

```
$ sed -n '\|/header|,\|footer|p' File
/header
2
footer
```

To save the changes to the file in-place:

```
sed -ni '\|/header|,\|footer|p' *  # GNU/Linux
```

Or:

```
sed -ni '' '\|/header|,\|footer|p' *  # OSX/BSD
```

Comment: The scope is the opposite, i need to keep what's inside the two tags, and remove all the rest

Answer (score 0):

This solution generates a list of the filenames with the header and footer line numbers - the generated list is used to construct a sed command run inside a loop to crop the files - the cropped file is created in a new directory called destdir - I assume the header and footer markers cannot be nested

```
files=$*
mkdir destdir
#grep header and footer line numbers with filename
grep -Hn -m2 -e'/header' -e'footer' $files|
# join pairs of consecutive lines to get header and footer line numbers on one line
sed -n 'N; s/\n/:/;p'|
# remove header and footer pattern matches and duplicate filename
cut -d: -f1,2,5|
# construct sed command to crop file
while IFS=: read file beg end; do
  echo $file
# remove what's between header and footer
#  sed "$beg,${end}d" $file >destdir/$file
# keep what's between header and footer
sed -n "$beg,${end}p;${end}q" $file >destdir/$file
done
```

Comment: It freezes before the cut -d: -f1,2,5|
I tried removing some files, but even with 4 files, it still freezes in that part...

Comment: How do you know it freezes before cut? What's the commandline you used to run the script? To debug build the pipeline one command at a time and check output, i.e. first the grep then add the sed then add the cut etc

Comment: I edited the code to show both sed commands for cropping inside or outside the block - use one or the other as you need